# All bar buttons on navigation bar have strange blue rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Does anybody know what is going on with these tab bar buttons?

- [sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKsVi.png)
- [sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYQXP.png)

As you can see strange blue rectangle appears both on buttons with my custom images and with standard style bar button.

As far as I know instance of `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't have a background property, so this behavior seems to me very odd.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. Until you post code we will have no way to know where the blue is coming from

Comment: all these elements were added in Interface Builder by drag and drop, and I have no specific code to setup these views.

Comment: Something doesn't look right to me. (1) You say these are UIBarButtons, but those belong on a UINavigationBar [top bar], *not* a UITabBar [bottom bar]. (2) In your second image I actually see a tab bar and *it is* the same color as the button. Are you mixing something up? (3) Both the nav and tab bars *do* have by default opaqueness set - which make them match the buttons you appear to have placed on the *actual* view controller view. Am I correct? **Bottom line:** you place *buttons* on a UIView (the base class of a view controller's view) and the other buttons on the other views.

Comment: (1) I meant `UIBarButtonItem` - it's supposed to be right on Navigation Bar.
(2) In the second image I think you've noticed a search bar, but it's not related to my problem.
(3) Hmmm... that doesn't make sense to me. What actually did you mean?